# Im using JSON to simply try to save a question and an answer to a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to save a question and an answer to a json file in a dictionary format. The issue I am having is when I update the old data with the new, The old data either gets over written or the data just appends it directly to the file and after I add 2 question/answers it gives me an error.

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 4 column 2 (char 52)
```

I have a button and an entry on a canvas when I click the button it should update the entry input into the json file. I'll need to do this many times as I am making a flashcard app and each entry will be a question.

The issue is update is not wrapping the added dictionary(question/answer) as it should.
This is a class method from the "window" class I created to add questions.

```py
    def add_question_to_list(self):
        new_question = self.add_question_entry.get()
        new_answer = self.add_answer_entry.get()

        question_dict = {
                "Question": new_question,
                "Answer": new_answer,
            }

        try:
            with open('math.json', "r") as data_file:
                data = json.load(data_file)
                print("got here 1")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            with open('math.json', "w") as data_file:
                json.dump(question_dict, data_file, indent=4)
        else:
            data.update(question_dict)
            print("got here 2")
            with open("math.json", "a") as data_file:
                json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
        finally:
            self.add_question_entry.delete(0, END)
            self.add_answer_entry.delete(0, END)
            print(question_dict)
            print("got here 3")
```

This is the code I have written and the frustrating part is it works perfectly on my windows computer. On my mac (i.7, Sonoma 14.2.10) it does not work.

This is the output into the JSON file "math.json"

```
{
    "Question": "yhnyhn",
    "Answer": "thnhtg"
}{
    "Question": "yhnty",
    "Answer": "tyhntyh"
}
```

^^^ NO OUTER WRAPPED CURLY BRACKETS...WHY?

python 3.10 on windows, python 3.10 and 3.12 on mac

I have tried several different variations of the code also changing between write and append mode on all possible levels, and rolling back python to the same version that I have on my windows computer(3.10) still no fix. any help would be greatly appreciated. I am just really confused as to why this works on my windows computer but not my mac.

let me know if you need screen shots or anything else. my first time posting on a website like this so I am not great at it yet! haha

thank you!

Comment: Your JSON file must not be just a dict.  It needs to be a LIST of dict.  You can start with an empty file containing `[]`.  Then your "add question" processing reads that list, appends the new question, and writes the list.  Remember that a JSON file must consist of a SINGLE object or list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
with open("math.json", "a") as data_file:
    json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
```

When you open the file in `"a"` mode, the existing file contents are kept, and  the new data is written directly after that (without a comma or anything in between).

And that leads to an invalid json file, because json files must contain only ONE outermost object.  But now your file contains TWO outermost objects, one after the other.

If you have a json file that contains a single dictionary and you want to update it to contain two dictionaries, you need to completely rewrite the file so that the outermost object is a list that contains the dictionaries.

i.e. your file needs to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "Question": "yhnyhn",
        "Answer": "thnhtg"
    },
    {
        "Question": "yhnty",
        "Answer": "tyhntyh"
    }
]
```

For consistency, you should probably always save the file as a list of dictionaries, even if it's a new file with only one dict.

There is also a variant of json called jsonlines, where each *line* in the file is its own separate json object, instead of the whole *file* being a json object.

That file would loke like this:

```
{"Question": "yhnyhn", "Answer": "thnhtg"}
{"Question": "yhnty", "Answer": "tyhntyh"}
```

You have to ensure your dictionaries are written as a single line, so you can't use `indent`.